# Issue parsing JSON file-Python

Tags: python, json

Have this section in one large JSON file

```
"UserDetailList": [
        {
            "UserName": "citrix-xendesktop-ec2-provisioning", 
            "GroupList": [], 
            "CreateDate": "2017-11-07T14:20:14Z", 
            "UserId": "AIDAI2YJINPRUEM3XHKXO", 
            "Path": "/", 
            "AttachedManagedPolicies": [
                {
                    "PolicyName": "AmazonEC2FullAccess", 
                    "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2FullAccess"
                }, 
                {
                    "PolicyName": "AmazonS3FullAccess", 
                    "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess"
                }
            ], 
            "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::279052847476:user/citrix-xendesktop-ec2-provisioning"
        },
```

Need to extract AttachedManagedPolicy.Policy name for user

Desired output:

```
"citrix-xendesktop-ec2-provisioning","AmazonEC2FullAccess"
"citrix-xendesktop-ec2-provisioning","AmazonS3FullAccess"
```

Some users don't have any policy at all so need some checking mechanism to avoid errors

```
with open('1.json') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
        for element in data['UserDetailList']:
            s = element['UserName'], element['AttachedManagedPolicies']
            print s
```

And getting

```
(u'citrix-xendesktop-ec2-provisioning', [{u'PolicyName': u'AmazonEC2FullAccess', u'PolicyArn': u'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2FullAccess'}, {u'PolicyName': u'AmazonS3FullAccess', u'PolicyArn': u'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess'}])
```

When added `element['AttachedManagedPolicies']['PolicyName']`

got: `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting error because `element['AttachedManagedPolicies']` is list not dictionary you need to iterate over `element['AttachedManagedPolicies']` and then access key as below:

```
[i['PolicyName'] for i in element['AttachedManagedPolicies']]
```

this will construct list of values for key `PolicyName`

As you said you have very large JSON structure you might have empty values or not values and for that you can proceed as below:

```
d = {
"UserDetailList": [
        {
            "UserName": "citrix-xendesktop-ec2-provisioning", 
            "GroupList": [], 
            "CreateDate": "2017-11-07T14:20:14Z", 
            "UserId": "AIDAI2YJINPRUEM3XHKXO", 
            "Path": "/", 
            "AttachedManagedPolicies": [
                {
                    "PolicyName": "AmazonEC2FullAccess", 
                    "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2FullAccess"
                }, 
                {
                    "PolicyName": "AmazonS3FullAccess", 
                    "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess"
                }
            ], 
            "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::279052847476:user/citrix-xendesktop-ec2-provisioning"
        } 
    ]
}

user_list = d.get("UserDetailList", None)  # if unable to fetch key then it will return None
if user_list:
    for user_detail in user_list:
        username = user_detail.get("UserName", None)
        policies = [i.get('PolicyName') for i in user_detail.get('AttachedManagedPolicies', []) if i.get('PolicyName', None)]  # empty list constructed if no policy exist
        print(username, policies)
```

Comment: almost there :`(u'citrix-xendesktop-ec2-provisioning', [u'AmazonEC2FullAccess', u'AmazonS3FullAccess'])
(u'rundeck-read-only-iam-permissions', [u'IAMReadOnlyAccess'])
(u'terraform_automated_python', [u'AdministratorAccess'])` how to get rid of `[()]` ? need to create CSV from results and need to get output like i posted in question

Comment: check for updated code.. you can use `.get()` method to overcome that issue